# Formal word or phrase for "under the radar"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to find a formal substitute for "under the radar." Consider this sentence:

> In the beginning, it's normal for companies to _______________.

The best I could think of would be "unnoticed." However, I'm hoping there is a phrase that doesn't involve a negative prefix like "un".

Comment: You can avoid, if you wish, a word that has a negation prefix, but simply based on the question as asked, I would not find any problem with a word such as *unnoticed*. In fact, I would consider it an excellent choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**obscurity**

> the condition of being unknown - [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/obscurity)

In the beginning, it's normal for companies to *operate in obscurity*.

Comment: I agree that some form of *obscure* is a good choice given your constraints. Alternatives to the suggested phrase include *remain in obscurity*, or simply, as I would recommend, *remain obscure*.

Answer (score 1):

> In the beginning, it's normal for companies to ______**be** under the radar____.

more formal: go undetected/ go unnoticed/ be unregistered

The context is not clear and it may be better to think about what you want to say exactly.  For example, not registering, not complying with tax obligations or being unlicensed.